# How to center Prestashop elements

Tags: css, prestashop, accordion, center

I personalize a part of my Prestashop site and i don't know what I can use for center this element :

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6oks.png)

Css :

```
  .active, .accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ccc; 
  }

  .accordion:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
  }
  
  .active:after {
    content: "\2212";
  }
  
  .panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    margin:  25px 25px 25px 25px;
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna center the words inside the container exist the property css text-align

**You must have include the html too if you want a better answer and what have you tried.**

As an example, these elements were centered using css, text-align:center;

[image]

Comment: Désolé de ne pas avoir répondu plus tôt, merci de votre réponse ^^